# how to show images in windows phone media viewer?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, bitmap

I am trying to show bitmap images using windows phone media viewer nuget package.

My code sample:

xaml code:

```
<controls:MediaViewer x:Name="MediaViewer"
                      InitiallyDisplayedElement="First" />
```

c# code:

```
ObservableCollection<object> slideShowImages = new ObservableCollection<object>();

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    string filepath = "Assets";
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);
    foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.png"))
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/" + filepath + "/" + file.Name, UriKind.Relative));
        slideShowImages.Add(img);
    }
    MediaViewer.Items = slideShowImages;
}
```

But in media viewer I am getting only a black screen. Is there any way to show bitmap images in windows phone media viewer?

Comment: Seems like you were not adding the created image to the collection slideShowImages.

Comment: I've missed that line in my question but my solution contains the line. The question has been edited. But still the result is same!